# fish: Unknown command: pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, konsole

today I am trying Garuda KDE Dr460nized and I am running python on it. But when I use pip for installing packages I open my Konsole and, an error comes like this

```
fish: Unknown command: pip
```

I thought I should write pip3 instead of pip but still, the same error comes

```
fish: Unknown command: pip3
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue in Garuda Linux. It is an Arch-based on Linux. Please tell me what is the solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It probably means that you don't have installed pip. Read this on how to install it https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1):

I think I have answered my question
I have to add:

```
python -m pip install packageName
```

It solved my error. If anyone can't solve their error you can see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip using a package called yaourt.
Follow the link below on now to get started with yaourt.

[install yaourt](https://www.tecmint.com/install-yaourt-in-arch-linux/)

after successful installation run

`yaourt pip3`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `python-pip` is not installed on your machine.
Please use the below command to install the `python-pip`.

I also faced the same issue. Not it's solved by this.

```sh
sudo pacman -S python2-pip               #Python 2
sudo pacman -S python-pip                #Python 3
```

verify your installation

```sh
pip help
```